# Take elements with class inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have several `iframe`s on the page. There are some elements with classname `test` inside of them. I need to set any `style` to them.

When I have only one `iframe`, I can use next construction:

```
$('#iframeId').contents().find('.test').css({background: '#f00'});
```

But I have several `iframe`s, so it would be great not to set concrete `iframe` and use construction like:

```
$('.test').css({background: '#f00'});
```

But it doesn't work, of course.

I used native `getElementsByClassName` before, but it doesn't work in `IE8`, where defect appears.

It may be stupid question, but.. Is there any construction like:

```
$(getElementById('something')).css({background: '#f00'});
```

It would be very helpful. I mean, wrap `JavaScript` object with `jQuery` and then use `jQuery` methods with them.

**Update:** I solved this problem with next construction:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementById('something').querySelectorAll('.test'), function (el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
});
```

But it's still doesn't work for `IE8`.

Comment: have you tried `$('iframe').contents().find('.test')...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try some thing like this

```
$("iframe").each(function(index){
   $(this).contents().find('.test').css({background: '#f00'});
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You may be running into one of two issues:
1) You are generally not able to modify the contents of iFrames returned from external domains, though that may not be the case here. If your iframes are pointing within your domain you should be fine.
2) ie8 has know problems with the "innerHTML" property, which jQuery's .css may rely on. instead, try using DOM methods:

```
document.getElementById("yourIframe").contentWindow.document.body.getElementById("innerIframeElement").setAttribute("style", "background:'#f00';"
```